# How to see BufferedImage in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, awt, bufferedimage, drawimage

I'm building a PongClone but I encounter a bug. **I think the bug is cause by JPanel.

I tried the Image instead of BufferedImage.
I tried the drawImage outside the paintComponent method.
I create to another panel and then add that panel inside a mainpanel.

Menu Class

```java
package me.pong;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestMenu {
    JFrame frame;

    public void createFrame () {
        TestMain main = new TestMain ();
        frame = new JFrame("TEST");
        frame.setSize (800, 450);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane ().add (main.panel);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

MainClass

```java
package me.pong;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class TestMain extends JPanel {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
    BufferedImage img;
    Graphics g;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        TestMain testMain = new TestMain ();
        TestMenu menu = new TestMenu ();
        menu.createFrame ();
        testMain.drawGraphics ();
    }

    public void drawGraphics(){
        panel.add (new TestMain ());
        img = new BufferedImage(800, 450, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = img.createGraphics ();
        g.drawString ("TEST STRING 2", 250,250);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent (g);
        g.clearRect (0,0,800,450);
        g.drawImage (img, 0,0,null);
        g.setColor (Color.white);
        g.drawString ("TEST STRING", 500,250);
        g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.drawRect (150,100,10,70);
    }
}
```

I expect the Image fill the component but actual output is little tiny box.
[Just like that](http://prntscr.com/n9b7dz)

**EDIT:** Delete the code and added MCVE/SSCCE Code(I didn't know that). Still same. If I add the image inside the frame it's works but other way doesn't. I know I'm missing something, but I don't know what that is.

**Yes. Problem caused by JPanel but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: ok this is a lot of convoluted code - you use static and final why?? do you have control over it or just looks cool??? I would sugesst rip it down to menu - see if you can display that

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) `public void update (Graphics g) {
        paint (g);
    }` What was your thinking there? If it ain't broke, don't 'fix' it. 3) Where does the custom painted panel return a sensible preferred size for use by the layout manager.. 4) Oh, NVM. Most of what I could ask would become obvious in an MCVE / SSCCE.

Comment: Many chunks of this code are not essential to demonstrate the problem. Post mcve / sscce as advised.

Comment: Just noticed another "what were you thinking there?"" moment. `static final PongGameMain game = new PongGameMain ()`. That is declared within the class structure of .. `PongGameMain`. (scratches head) Also `static final JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel ();` .. don't declare `static` for GUI components. It is an hack to cover a faulty design, and leads to even more problems. Figure out how to do that with a non static component and doing so will often solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for all answers. First of all I edited the code.

Comment: @gpasch I was gonna fix them all later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra panel declared within the custom painted class that **is a** panel was not only unnecessary, but the source of problems. See further comments in code.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class TestMain extends JPanel {

    JFrame frame;
    // Not needed or useful! 
    //JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
    BufferedImage img;
    Graphics g;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMain testMain = new TestMain();
        testMain.createFrame();
        testMain.drawGraphics();
    }

    public void createFrame() {
        TestMain main = new TestMain();
        frame = new JFrame("TEST");
        frame.setSize(400, 250);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.getContentPane().add(main.panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(main);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void drawGraphics() {
        //panel.add(new TestMain());
        add(new TestMain());
        img = new BufferedImage(800, 450, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = img.createGraphics();
        g.drawString("TEST STRING 2", 250, 250);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 450);
        // all JComponent instances are image observers
        //g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        // NEW! Otherwise invisible
        g.setColor(Color.RED); 
        g.drawString("TEST STRING", 200, 100);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(150, 100, 10, 70);
    }
}
```

As an aside:

1. That code still has problems, but I thought it best to stick closely to fixing only the immediate problem.
2. The easiest way to display a `BufferedImage` is to show it in a `JLabel` via an `ImageIcon`.