# How to create a JLabel that updates on a click?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I am attempting to learn GUI programming in Java, and currently I have a frame that contains a button and a label. When the button is clicked, a dialog pops up that says how many times the button has been clicked. I want to do essentially the same thing for the label, but I can't get it to update past saying it has been clicked zero times.

Here is the code for the button:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CountButton extends JButton {
    private int counter = 0;

    public CountButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                counter++;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have clicked the button "
                        + counter + " times!");
            }
        });
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Here is my attempted implementation:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class LayoutPractice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Layout Practice");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1020,700);
        JPanel panelOne = new JPanel();

        //Button portion of frame
        JButton button = new CountButton("Click me for a dialog!");
        panelOne.add(button);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("The button has been pressed 0 times.");
        panelOne.add(label);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText("The button has been pressed " + 
                    ((CountButton) button).getCounter() + " times.");
            }
        });

        frame.add(panelOne, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Edit: I've changed the code to add a listener event to the button so that when it is clicked, it changes the text of the label via label.setText(), but now my problem is that the first button click doesn't update it. It only begins to update after clicking it twice, and then the number of clicks is one behind the actual number of clicks.

Comment: *"I have a suspicion that this is because once the label has been created, it can't be updated."* Of course it can be updated. It just isn't updated according to a change in a variable used to initialize it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson So how can I go about updating it after initializing it then?

Comment: I'll let you know after I see an SSCCE / MCVE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Okay, I think that edit should satisfy as an SSCCE.

Comment: *"I think that edit should satisfy as an SSCCE"* Test it! Start a new project in your IDE, copy/paste the code and check it runs ***without any changes.*** If it doesn't, it's not an MCVE / SSCCE of a run-time problem, because it is neither Complete nor Self Contained. I just posted an MCVE / SSCCE on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604679/418556). Note how it has imports, a class structure .. everything that's needed to run it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Alright, lets try it again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ActionListeners:

1. one added in the constructor of your button class.
2. the second added in your main method.

Swing invokes ActonListeners in the reverse order the listener is added to the component.

So you update the text on the label before the counter variable has been incremented.

A better design is to create a JPanel class. The you create an instance of the panel and add it to the frame. This class would contain:

1. the button
2. the label
3. the counter.

You create the components and add them to the panel and add a single listener to the button.

With this design all the variable are defined in the same class. So all the components can work together with one another. Don't define Swing components in a main() method.

For example see the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for a better design of your code showing how to create a panel with multiple related components.

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I needed, and it made the program a lot less ugly. Thanks!